# Как привязать диалоговое окно  к пункту "Меню"?

Tags: windows, окно, c++, visual-c++

Была готовая программа на  VC++.

Я создал одно диалоговое окно, и кнопку в пункте меню, которая открывает (должна открывать) диалоговое окно.

Но есть проблема: я не знаю, как привязать это окно. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как привязать его (диалоговое окно)?

Пытался найти в гугле - там тьма другой информации, в которой потеряна нужная.

Comment: скучно :))

Comment: А в чём проблема? (1) Вы не можете сделать так, чтобы по выбору пункта меню выполнился ваш код? (2) Вы не можете из этого кода открыть новое окно?

Comment: @VladD, я не знаю, как открыть мой код. 
в программе появляется нужный пункт меню, но он не активен. я не знаю, как сделать, что бы при нажатии на эту кнопку открывалось созданное мною окно.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что значит "открыть код"?

Comment: @VladD, в смысли, запустить мое диалоговое окно, которое я создал.

Comment: @andrw: А как у вас главное окно открывается? У вас вообще какая платформа: WinAPI, MFC, Qt, WinForms, WPF?